# JLabel tooltiptext not showing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tooltip, jlabel

I expected this to be very simple and straightforward, but tooltiptext is not showing upon hovering the mouse over. I tried printing the text and it prints correctly. Any comments what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class gui2 extends JFrame {
private JLabel item1;
public gui2() {
    super("The title bar");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    item1 = new JLabel("label 1");
    item1.setToolTipText("This is a message");
    String str = item1.getToolTipText();
    System.out.println(str);
    add(item1);
}

   class gui {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    gui2 g2 = new gui2();
    g2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    g2.setSize(400, 200);
    g2.setVisible(true);
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not compile even if you add the imports. Here is your code corrected and working :

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Gui {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Window window = new Window();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(400, 200);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Window extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel jlabel;

    public Window() {
        super("The title bar");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jlabel = new JLabel("label 1");
        jlabel.setToolTipText("This is a message");
        String str = jlabel.getToolTipText();
        System.out.println(str);
        add(jlabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @resticteur. I didn't paste the code properly. My code was compiling and showing the label except the tooltip text wasn't working. I will be careful to paste code that compiles. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @restricteur your code does not compile.

This is due to the fact that your class `gui` which holds the `main(..)` is nested within another class, hence no `static` declaration of method is allowed unless the nested class is marked `static`. ( I simply moved/un-nested `Gui` out from `Gui2`)

Besides that your code does work, I think you are being hasty - **hold the mouse over** `JLabel` **for like 3-4 seconds** and you should see the `ToolTip` appear:

(using your code with no compilation error of course):
[image]

**Suggestions on code:**

1) Please watch java naming conventions i.e class names should begin with a capital letter and each new word thereafter should also i.e `gui` becomes `Gui` or `GUI` but I prefer the former.

2) Dont call `setSize` on `JFrame` use and= appropriate `LayoutManager` and call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible (but after components have been added).

3) Dont extend `JFrame` unnecessarily simply create an instance and use that.

4) Always create and manipulate Swing Components on [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)` block.

5) Opt for `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` unless using `Timer`s as this will allow `main(..)` to continue regardless if GUI is exited.

Here is code with above fixes:

[image]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class Gui2 {

    private JLabel item1;
    private JFrame frame;

    public Gui2() {
        frame = new JFrame("The title bar");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        item1 = new JLabel("label 1");
        item1.setToolTipText("This is a message");
        String str = item1.getToolTipText();
        System.out.println(str);
        frame.add(item1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Gui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Gui2();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. You were almost right about me being hasty,  I wasn't hovering the mouse over the JLabel as I should have been. I kept moving the mouse over the window, but not quite on the label. My bad. Your other comments are appreciated and I will work on them.